# EF - proper way to handle several many-many mappings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have a project with quite a few entities, but several of them link in an interesting way. `User` and `PurchaseOrder` each have two many-many relationships between them to keep track of 1) whether a given user has looked at a purchase order, or 2) needs to be alerted of a change to a purchase order. I use fluent EF mapping.

**The rest of this is information specific to my situation, but the basic question is this: How should I best handle this setup (two tables with two separate M:N relationships between each other) in EF?**

A greatly simplified diagram:

[image: DB diagram]

I tried the code below, but I'm receiving an error when `.Clear()` is called. This error may not be exact, I've changed the code quite a bit since then trying to figure this out.

```
A relationship from the 'PurchaseOrder' AssociationSet is in the 'Deleted' /
state. Given multiplicity constraints, a corresponding 'User' must also in /
the 'Deleted' state.
```

If I try to add to the list using `po.UsersViewed.Add(currentUser)` and then `_poService.Update(po)`, I get this error. `currentUser` and `po` are both proxies pulled from the DB.

```
An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key /
properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return /
null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception.
```

`User` class:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
public string Email { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrdersViewed { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<PurchaseOrder> PurchaseOrdersAlert { get; set; }
```

`PurchaseOrder` class:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string PONumber { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<User> UsersViewed { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<User> UsersAlert { get; set; }
```

Relevant part of the `PurchaseOrder` fluent mapping is below. `User` mapping has no relevant lines.

```
HasMany(s => s.UsersViewed)
    .WithMany(s => s.PurchaseOrdersViewed)
    .Map(cs =>
        {
            cs.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            cs.MapRightKey("PurchaseOrderId");
            cs.ToTable("PurchaseOrderViewed");
        });

    HasMany(s => s.UsersAlert)
        .WithMany(s => s.PurchaseOrdersAlert)
        .Map(cs =>
        {
            cs.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            cs.MapRightKey("PurchaseOrderId");
            cs.ToTable("PurchaseOrderAlert");
        });
```

These are almost always called by this code. `po` is the proxy for the `PurchaseOrder` entity pulled from the DB with EF.

```
po.PurchaseOrdersAlert = po.PurchaseOrdersViewed;
po.PurchaseOrdersViewed.Clear();
```

Comment: Don't model your business logic in the database, You could maybe manage with enumerator in one many-to-many table declaring the state of the PurchaseOrder for the User.

Comment: I agree with @JanneMatikainen. That was my first thought as well.
But even so, you should not assign one list to the other. EF actually creates instances of EntityCollection<T> wherever you use ICollection<T> and those have some logic to keep track of the changes. Good practice is to make the collection setter protected.

Comment: @JanneMatikainen Do you mean keep only one join table with the `PurchaseOrderId` and `UserId`, then an additional column that determines whether it's viewed or read (using an `int` constant)? I would remove the entry entirely if the user hasn't marked it viewed _and_ there's no alert.

Comment: @Franky I'm not sure how I would do it without assigning one list to the other. Would I need to update each row with the new value corresponding to its read/alert status?

Comment: @Vaindil: If you keep both lists, you could do a po.PurchaseOrdersAlert.AddRange(po.PurchaseOrdersViewed); instead of the assignment.

Comment: @Franky Ah, okay, I see now. How would I use the lists though? Janne indicated that I shouldn't be using two, from what I understand.

Comment: If you change it with @Janne Matikainen approach, you create a new entity with a UserId and a PurchaseOrderId to simulate the ManyToMany. Add a State property (an enum with the values Viewed and Alert). With this your two entities only need one list and you set the state to Alert instead of moving them from one list to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer really depends on what data you want to gather to the entity called UserPurchaseOrder relation. To me it seems like you are interested in at three things.

1. If the purchase order should be sent to the user in the first place.
2. If the user has then viewed it after it has been sent to user.
3. If the user is interested in receiving alerts regarding this purchase order.

You can model this with a flagged enum

```
[Flags]
public enum PurchaseOrderStatus
{
    None = 0,
    Sent = 1 << 0, // 1
    Received = 1 << 1, // 2
    Enrolled = 1 << 2, // 4
}
```

First you send the PO to user by adding relation with status = 1, after user has seen the PO sent to him you alter the status to 3 (1 + 2). If the user then is interested in seeing the alerts he/she enrolls and the status is updated to 7 (1 + 2 + 4).